# Sticky navbar: Overlapping image in navbar should be only partially sticky

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I put on my site a sticky navbar that I took from bootstrap and which works pretty fine. Included in that navbar, I want an image that should appear much bigger/taller in size than the navbar. When you open the page, this image should appear in full size. When you scroll, the image and navbar together should move up to the top of the screen. Therefore, the overlapping part of the image should disappear and only the rest of it should remain visible sticky like the navbar.

I'm new to CSS, so what I tried is some random stuff I found on this and some other forums but that didn't work so far.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row sticky-top">
      <div class="col-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#top"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg" style="width: 100%"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#1">menu item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#2">menu item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#3">menu item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#4">menu item 4</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#5">menu item 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The logo image and the navbar both appear sticky with their top border, their bottom border is not in line.
The image should show what I mean:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUZmM.png)

Comment: It's hard to help you without your CSS and an image of what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: I use the CSS provided by the linked bootstrap CSS file.
What I want as a result can be seen in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUZmM.png

Comment: The <div class="row sticky-top"> should be only as tall as the <li class="nav-item">, when they have a text link in it. So even though I include an image into that sticky row, that is bigger than the text links, the overlapping top parts of the image should scroll away, too.

Answer (score 0):

For the overlapping part I recommend to use z–Index property on nav and img

Comment: The image is INCLUDED into the navbar, it's img-tag is part or it, but the image should be by far taller than the actual navbar without making the whole navbar that tall. The navbar should remain only as tall as the rest of the menu items. The much bigger image part should spread out from the navbar and so "scroll away" when you scroll up until the navbar sticks to the top. In that situation then, only the rest of the image, that is within the navbar, should be visible.Is that only possible when you cut the image in two parts,of which one is over the navbar and the other is part of the navbar?

Comment: Uhm why not just replace the image outside the nav container instead and make it another div that can overlap the nav.

Comment: That's a good idea. Do you know a way how to make this div "partially sticky", I mean, in a way that only the lower third sticks same as the nav bar, while all the rest of the page will scroll under the navbar and the image-third?

Comment: try playing with absolute and relative positioning to get what you need. Just do the google or search so for it, there are plenty of threads.  Personally I don't have a exact solution in mind right now.